Question about cube of graph
How can I prove that if $G$ is connected, then any edge of $G^3$ is contained in some simple cycle?
I took an edge $uv$ and supposed that it’s not in any cycle, so doesn’t exist a sequence of vertices $v-v_{1}-…-v_{k}-u$, but I don’t see how to proceed …
P.s Cube of graph $G$ - such graph $G^3$ that there's edge $uv$ if and only if $u, v$ are connected by path of length $<=3$ in original graph

Consider a few cases depending on how your edge appeared: is it originally from $G$, or appeared in $G^2$ or in $G^3$.

I think we need to assume that $G$ has at least $3$ vertices.
Let $uv$ be an edge of $G^3$.
So there is a path in $G$ between $u$ and $v$ of length $l\leq 3$. Let's go case by case (for minimum $l$):
$l=1$
In this case $uv$ is an edge in $G$. Since there is some third vertex and $G$ is connected, there must exist a path from $u$ and $v$ to this third vertex. So either $u$ and/or $v$ has a second edge $e$ leaving from it. Let $w$ be the other end point of $e$. In any case, the triangle $uvw$ is present in $G^3$ and we're done.
$l=2$
Now there is a path $u-w-v$ in $G$. So of course this path is present in $G^3$ too and we have the triangle.
$l=3$
Similarly like in $l=2$ (remember we're doing this for the minimum $l$ so the path can't be $u-v-u-v$, it must contain other vertices in the middle).
